# jahia add tomcat web context

Tags: java, tomcat, jahia

For technical reasons we need to add a web context to jahia application so we add the tomcat web context (ex : /myApp). 
We encounter some issues :

- Urls image in slider have the context 2 time (/myApp/myApp/), so the urls are wrong, no image is appeared.
- If we make an external link in menu to point in the same domain (relative root path like /my/new/path) it adds in server side the context (/myApp) so it create a url like /myApp/my/new/pah that we do not want. (We had /../my/new/path so it works).

Comment: hi You have change jahia admin handle to change context

Comment: I have big experience for jahia development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from a external module that doing wrong relative url, not from Jahia core. It's resolved with the last version of the module.